# Creating dynamically large table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to create dynamically a table using JavaScript.

**Here is the code I'm using (or here http://liveweave.com/mqG5iT):**

```
 function Process(){
         CreatTable(['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email']);

     }
    function CreatTable(data) {
    var checkbox;
    var table;
    var thead;
    var tr;
    var th;
    var tbody;

    tablearea = document.getElementById('ShowDataID');
    table = document.createElement('table');
    table.id = "ContactsTable";
    thead = document.createElement('thead');
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

    //create columns input checkbox column
    checkbox = CreateHTMLElement("chkBoxAllEmails", "chkBoxAllEmails", "SelectAllEmails()", "checkbox", "false");
    th = document.createElement('th');
    th.appendChild(checkbox);
    tr.appendChild(th);
    thead.appendChild(tr);

    //create columns FirstName,LastName,Emails
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var headerTxt = document.createTextNode(data[i]);
        th = document.createElement('th');
        th.appendChild(headerTxt);
        tr.appendChild(th);
        thead.appendChild(tr);
    }
    table.appendChild(thead);

    //create rows and addind to table
    for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        checkbox = CreateHTMLElement("11", "11", "11", "checkbox", "11");
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));

        tr.cells[0].appendChild(checkbox);               tr.cells[1].appendChild(document.createTextNode('John'+i.toString()));
        tr.cells[2].appendChild(document.createTextNode('McDowell'));
        tr.cells[3].appendChild(document.createTextNode('ddd@gmail.com'));

        tbody.appendChild(tr);
        table.appendChild(tbody);
    }
   document.getElementById("TablePagingArea").appendChild(table);
    //return table;
}

function CreateHTMLElement(id, name, onclick, type, value) {
    var HTMLElement = document.createElement('input');
    HTMLElement.id = id;
    HTMLElement.name = name;
    HTMLElement.onclick = onclick;
    HTMLElement.type = type;
    HTMLElement.value = value;
    return HTMLElement;
}
```

With a small set of data 1000-3000 rows it works relatively well but, some of the data set contains upwards of 5000 rows which causes Firefox to crash and close or become unresponsive.

My question is: is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: use pagination. A table with 1000+ of rows is useless in most cases

Comment: And sorting, and filtering.

Comment: I use pagination on already created table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Most efficient way to create a bunch of elements is to create a string and create element from this string.
2. Most efficient way to create a string of element is to join from array

So you should refactor your code to

1. Create an array of elements like `a[i] = "<tr><intput type='checkbox'></tr>";`
2. Join an array to get one string `var s = a.join()`;
3. Create DOM elements like  `var div = document.createElement('div'); div.innerHTML = s;`

Comment: I need to make pagination on the table.Also evry row in table has checkbox when I move from one page to another I need the check box remember his state if I use your aproch how can I make to remember the check box state(check or uncheck)?

Comment: Your question was "is there a better way to accomplish my task", right? There is nothing about pagination. I recommend you to take a look at the javascript libs like [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/), [angular.js](https://angularjs.org/) etc to bind your data to the DOM